# Did Mesoamericans eat Chihuahua dogs?

Tags: nutrition, dogs, united-states

There are multiple online sources that claim the Chihuahua dog breed was often eaten by the Mesoamerican cultures who lived there before the arrival of the Europeans.

For example, [this site](http://lostworlds.org/ancient-chihuahuas-roamed-eaten-southeastern-u-s/) claims that:

> The early Spanish conquistadors who explored the region in the 1500s noted that several tribes raised “little dogs” which they kept very fat in order to eat. Apparently this food was reserved for the elites of the towns. The Spanish also noted these “little dogs” were mute.
>
> Scholars apparently thought the Spanish accounts couldn’t be trusted and suggested the animals referred to as “little dogs” were more likely oppossums. Yet a similar custom of elites eating fattened dogs was common in Mexico. The breed usually eaten was the Techichi which was a mute dog that the modern Chihuahua is thought to be derived from. The dog pots in Colima in west Mexico show fattened Techichis which provide visual evidence for this practice. The dog pots in the southeastern U.S. show fattened Chihuahuas which suggest this tradition was also practiced in the southeast.

[This thread](http://message.snopes.com/showthread.php?t=8978) on the Snopes forums also makes a similar claim.

Are there any reliable sources that show the Chihuahua dog breed was frequently eaten by the Mesoamericans?

Comment: If only to shut the annoying little buggers up! ;)

Comment: Not sure about Mesoamerica but Lacota considered dog meat a delicacy, IIRC. So it's not out of realm of possibility

Comment: I'm trying hard to understand why this question was even asked. Dog meat is considered to be a delicacy in many different cultures.

Comment: Not that I would eat dog meat myself, but that's mostly because I come from a culture where eating dogs is frowned upon. In fact, I love dogs. I've buried (and never eaten) four dogs over the course of my life, and I have three that are still alive, ages three to fourteen. I will rue the day when the oldest one dies. She is a fantastically good dog. Look at my icon. It's three dogs running on the beach, all with their tongues hanging out.

Comment: @DavidHammen AFAIK, the Spanish conquistadors did not eat dogs, and as a result the tales may have been fabricated in order to emphasise the barbarous nature of the natives.

Comment: @MarchHo -- Don't be so culturalistly judgmental. Even those of European descent eat predators such as bear and tuna. Fish that eat plants aren't nearly as tasty as are fish that eat other fish.

Comment: @MarchHo The Spanish conquerors ate American dogs.  See page 5 of this book for example https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Philosophical_Magazine/hFgwAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=eat+Techichi&pg=PA5&printsec=frontcover